# Get storage type of local path

Tags: android, storage, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

If I have paths like following:

1. `/storage/emulated/0/...`
2. `/storage/UsbDriveA/...`
3. `/sdcard/...`

**I basically have following questions:**

- How do I find out which storage they are located on? (USB stick, external storage, internal storage)
- How do I find out which type they are? (primary storage (I have direct r/w access), secondary storage (on android >=4.4, I don't have direct w access and I need to acquire this right through the `Storage Access Framework` if I need it))
- How do I find out what the ROOT path is?

**Results that I want**

1. This is: internal storage, primary storage, root path is `/storage/emulated/0/`
2. This is: USB Stick, secondary storage, root path is `/storage/UsbDriveA/`
3. This is: external storage, secondary storage, root path is `/sdcard/`

I know the paths may vary from phone to phone, so how do I find out which path is located on which storage and which permissions I do have on which paths? I know I can guess by the names of the path, but I'm interested in a reliable way that works on all (or at least on most) phones...

Answer (score 0):

You need to check access for every primary and secondary storage through Environment class. You should do something like this:

```
Boolean canWrite =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canWrite(); if(canWrite)// do something with externalstorage
```

and use  Environment.getRootDirectory() for internal root

for USB you need to check it with

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE"));
    return intent.getExtras().getBoolean("connected");
}
```

Comment: That's not new to me... Actually it's all about finding out which path belongs to which storage and to be able to find the ROOT path of any storage. I want to tell the user to select the root of their sd card or usb stick and I afterwards want to check if they did select the correct path (not a sub directory and not the wrong storage)

Comment: As described here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29 the getExternalStorageDirectory() method allows you to point to the top tevel(root) directory of a external storage.